# Display Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

Using SQL Reporting i successfully deploy reports 
[image: pic]

now i want to call this reports in .aspx form and there in .aspx form there is a reports tab now i want when user click on this tab then how to link this reports to .aspx form and also  i want to show this several reports which i created and user able to display these reports

[image: reports]

how i done this?

any idea?

Comment: Hi do you want only show your report right? can you tell me if you need solution in c# o vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this example could help you

> ```
> private void loadReport()
> {
>     rpt.Visible = true;
>     rpt.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
>     rpt.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
> ```

```
    rpt.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://MyServer/ReportServer/");
    rpt.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/MyFolder/MyReportName";

    List<ReportParameter> parametros = new List<ReportParameter>();

    parametros.Add(new ReportParameter("codClient", codClient);
    parametros.Add(new ReportParameter("codProduct", codProduct);

    rpt.ServerReport.SetParameters(parametros);
    rpt.ServerReport.Refresh();

}
```

after in you button put this

> ```
> protected void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   loadReport();
> }
> ```